# How do I export math terms from org-mode to S5?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, mathjax

S5 is a sparse specification for slide presentations that run in the browser. It looks quite nice, and there's a couple of exporters for org-mode.

I am running Org 7.9.2 in Emacs 23, and I have a nearly working example:

```
* Joint diagonalization

    Why does this work?

  - Covariance matrices are commuting normal matrices 
   \begin{equation*}
    (A^*A)
   \end{equation*}
```

This produces one slide, but the equation snippets don't appear as evaluated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out as I was writing the question, but it's worth mentioning as I couldn't find the answer anywhere else. As given in [this page](http://orgmode.org/manual/Math-formatting-in-HTML-export.html#Math-formatting-in-HTML-export), the standard way for org-mode to export math into HTML is to use MathJax, set up to connect to the org-mode website to get at the script. This applies as well for S5.

That means you have to have a working connection to render that, or you have to set the path option in your org file like this: `#+HTML_MATHJAX: path:"/MathJax/MathJax.js"`

Also, if you run NoScript like me, you also have to make sure the domain specified is allowed to run scripts in your browser, or it'll never work ;)